# Is there a way to detect the status of the Esri world imagery basemap service programmatically prior to opening an MXD?

Tags: python, imagery, web-service, arcgis-10.8

We have a web application that programmatically exports an MXD to a PDF.  In this MXD, we have Esri's world imagery service added in one of the dataframes.  However, when the imagery service is down or very slow, it prevents the MXD from opening and/or exporting.  It's the same behavior if you try to open the MXD manually as well.  If the imagery service is down, the MXD simply hangs up or stalls out when you try to open.

So what I want to do is somehow test the status of the imagery service in Python or JavaScript prior to running the MXD export step.  If the imagery service is ok, then proceed.  If the imagery service is down or slow, then switch to a different imagery service etc.  Any ideas?

Comment: ping https://status.arcgis.com/ ?  never had an issue opening a basemap with imagery in arcgis - is that a network/internet issue?

Comment: There was an outage yesterday and today, but unfortunately, status.arcgis.com wasn't picking up the issue.  I posted on the esri community forums and others were having the same problem.  Interestingly, the issue was isolated to Desktop users only.  ArcGIS Pro users didn't have the issue.

Comment: This isn't helpful to your question, but are you sure the MXD is truly hanging?  I've found that when a web source is not able to connect, the map takes much longer to open but will eventually come up with the red exclamation point for it.  

Or - maybe helpful: can you simply put a timeout in the code, so that if it doesn't open within some normal time frame then it bails out and tries your alternate imagery service?